# Change max columns display for cross sell products

Tags: css, magento-1.9, display, product

I'm using Magento 1.9 and I have my max columns display for the cross sell products set to 3.

I would like to increase it to 5 or 6 columns, without messing with the css.

This is what I found in the styles.css

```
  .products-grid > li:nth-child(even) {
    margin-right: 3.7037%;
  }
  .products-grid > li {
    width: 30.8642%;
    margin-right: 3.7037%;
  }
```

Comment: reduce width: 30.8642%; to display more products on same line and may be margin too. can you share link to website?

Comment: There is no avoiding css

Comment: @tech2017 thank you! the website is http://www.hdiscount.it (italian)

Comment: @Brian I didn't modify the css anymore, just edited the crosssell.phtml file (under templates/checkout) changing the 
class="products-grid products-grid--max-3-col" to
class="products-grid products-grid--max-5-col"